# Increase opacity of a floor plane along the path travelled by a cube

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, graphic-effects, transparency

I have a plane object (a normal Unity 3D Plane, but it can be a complex floor in the future) and a cube is moving on the plane.

Currently, the plane is transparent. I want to make the plane opaque as the cube passes along it. But I want it to do this thing in an incremental way. I mean that **as the cube passes through the area, the passed area becomes opaque**.

I can do this by cutting the plane into smaller pieces and then, as the cube pass through each piece, [I change its opacity using this logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALE9Z_wxavg). But dividing the plane into smaller chunks, each of which is a separate models, is not an efficient approach. Is there any way to do this using shaders or something else?

Comment: "Opaque" is not a verb. Have you looked into past Q&A about painting effects? It seems to me this is the same as painting an image or mask, except that the cube is your paintbrush instead of the mouse cursor.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the title but i don't think it is related to painting as I am not willing to change or apply color. I want to enable the same color of the object but as my cube passes through the object. Nevertheless thanks for the "painting effects" hint. I will check it.

Comment: Are you trying to change the alpha of the whole object or the part of the object that is masked by the cube?

Comment: Hint: the alpha value (transparency) is part of the colour. So you can paint into just the alpha channel, or use a texture that is only alpha.

Comment: @Mangata Not the whole which is easy i have explained. I want to do it partly like as my cube move on plane, the area which has passed by the cube should get opaque.

Comment: basically a scratch off effect? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101453/in-unity3d-how-do-i-create-an-efficient-scratch-card-effect. Instead of having an area covered, thats your original map. The scratched parts are your transparence/ opaque

Comment: Not like this , its like clipping the model.